# Petapoco and Azure SQL Connection Pool

Tags: connection-pooling, azure-sql-database, petapoco

At the heart of Petapoco.cs there is the function OpenShareConnection.
I believe this cannot take advantage of the Connection Pool in SQL Azure.
I am monitoring my connections and the connection count grows above the pool limit.

Anyone has done some improvements?

Here is the OpenShareConnection (from Petapoco open source):

```
    public void OpenSharedConnection()
    {
        if (_sharedConnectionDepth == 0)
        {                
            //read the connection string from web.config and 
            //create a new connection
            _sqlConnection = _factory.CreateConnection(); 
            _sqlConnection.ConnectionString = _connectionString;


            // Wrap this method with a retry policy.
            _sqlConnection.Open();

            _sqlConnection = OnConnectionOpened(_sqlConnection);

            if (KeepConnectionAlive)
                _sharedConnectionDepth++;       // Make sure you call Dispose
        }
        _sharedConnectionDepth++;
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

As far as I can see Petapoco is fighting the basic premise behind ADO connection pooling not creating a new SQLConnection(string connectionString) and then performing a .Close() method when the connection is closed.

Not surprising there are nothing but crickets chirping on this 4 yr. 9 month old question.